# apache configuration on windows server for high traffic

Tags: windows, apache

hi there i am trying to deploy laravel project on my deticated server which has two processors about 32 core and 128 giga ram
i am using apache longue as web server and using mpm winnt (this is the allowed mpm for windows
my problem is when i testing using jmeter i get about 90% of requests quicly but the rest requests take too long time[image] to response and i can not understand why ??
[image]

it seems like those requests hold in queue but i really dont no why
my winnt conf is
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
ThreadsPerChild        1920
MaxConnectionsPerChild   1000000
</IfModule>

i am trying to get 2000 request per second

Comment: It doesn't matter how many resources you throw at it, Windows isn't made for this type of thing.

Comment: thanks for reply andy ... did you mean that apache on windows can not do what i need?

Comment: Apache is resource intensive, windows is resource intensive, Laravel is resource intensive and 2000 RPS is resource intensive. I recommend you minimize the resource requirements for as many of these as you can.
NginX or lighttpd would be significantly less heavy. Linux too - with both of these I imagine you could achieve your goals have room to spare.